# JMeter Point-to-Point test of ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jmeter

I am trying to use the Point-to-Point functionality of JMeter to test ActiveMQ. I am following the documentation [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html).

In this page there is the following against the Communication Style 'Request Response':

> This means that you need at least a service that responds to the requests.

What are my options for obtaining a service that responds to the requests? Is it possible to configure ActiveMQ to do this, or to change a JMS property in the Point-to-Point panel in JMeter to get it to do this automatically? If not, are there any simple apps out there that will just reply to a message and send the reply on another queue?

I am using ActiveMQ 5.5.1 and JMeter 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe ActiveMQ provides a service to automatically respond to requests. ActiveMQ is simply a broker/message router. JMeter is your "client". So you still need a server (which is the "service" mentioned). Since you are testing Point-to-Point, you will need a JMS server that uses queues instead of topics. Your options for the server are to write your own code or find some synchronous JMS server code/test tool such as the following:
http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

In that example code, you will have to change `message.getJMSReplyTo()` to some queue name that you will then use in JMeter's `JNDI Name Reply Queue  (Q.RPL)` field in the following line:

```
this.replyProducer.send(message.getJMSReplyTo(), response);
```

And in JMeter, you will need to set `JNDI Name Request Queue  (Q.REQ)` to whatever `messageQueueName` is set to in that example code. Default is `client.messages`